# Обращение к чекнутым чекбоксам

Tags: c#, wpf

//update
   Коротко: Есть группа чекбоксов, необходимо менять форму, для этого есть массив mass[I,j], в зависимости от значений в этом массиве будет меняться фон, форма у выбранных чекбоксов.

Значения массива меняются через кнопку, выбранные чекбоксы соответсвтвуют элементам массива.

Массив использую для сохранения состояния чекбоксов

[image: Примерно так выглядит]

// update 2

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Border  x:Name="checkbx" BorderBrush="#FFC6C6C7" BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">

                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="checkbx" Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="btn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="test2" Background="#FFFFFFFF" CornerRadius="10, 10, 10, 10" BorderBrush="#FFC6C6C7" BorderThickness="1.5">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="test2" Property="Background" Value="#FFCCCDD1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid  Margin="0,0,2,-1">

    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx1" Style="{DynamicResource MyCheckBox}" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="62,59,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx4" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="62,104,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx7" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="62,150,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx2" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="107,59,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx5" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="107,104,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx8" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="107,150,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx3" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="152,60,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx6" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="152,105,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx9" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="152,150,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource btn}" Content="Выбрать" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="82,205,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Функции

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    cbs = new CheckBox[,] { { cbx1, cbx2, cbx3 },{ cbx4, cbx5, cbx6 },{ cbx7, cbx8, cbx9 } };
}
CheckBox[,] cbs;
int[,] Mass = new int[3, 3];

private void Sostoyanie()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            if (Mass[i, j] == 1)
            {
                cbs[i, j].Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
                cbs[i, j].Background = Brushes.Gray;
            }
}

private void CheckCheckbx()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            if (cbs[i, j].IsChecked == true) Mass[i, j] = 1;
}


private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckCheckbx();
    Sostoyanie();
}
```

Comment: Вы смешиваете понятия WinForms и WPF. **1.** В WinForms используются формы, в WPF такого понятия нет, есть окна. **2.** В WPF принято работать по MVVM паттерну, у которого одно из правил строго на строго запрещает знать об элементах окна (View) из кода. **3.** Исходя из 2-го пункта в WPF принято использовать привязки (Binding), это основная суть всего WPF!. Что же происходит у вас в коде? У вас нету не MVVM, не привязок, да и окна называются как Form1. Вы уверены, что хотите работать на WPF?

Comment: Да к сожалению, поэтому и пытаюсь понять...

Comment: Объясните свою задачу полностью и подробней (зачем чекбоксы (их смысл), можно даже скрин того, что в итоге хотите увидеть), сегодня, как освобожусь (если не ответят ранее) попробую помочь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ дополнил, надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не знаю что произошло, но спустя 4 часа все заработало...

Comment: Как понять "значения массивов меняются через кнопку" ? Да и что вообще такое, эти ваши массивы? От куда они берутся и какая роль?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Необходимо динамически менять цвет у кнопки и сохранять это после перезапуска. Для это и нужен массив.

Comment: То есть при выборе одного из CheckBox-ов меняется цвет у кнопки?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да! Выбранные чекбоксы через нажатие допустим кнопки "+1" меняют свой цвет на заданный в функции. Осталось только понять как менять форму. Через cbs[i, j].Background = Brushes.Gray; изменяю цвет, а вот CornerRadius не знаю пока как изменить...

Comment: А вы можете показать XAML код? А то мы вроде говорим об одном, а потом вдруг появляется CornerRadius, который обычно ставиться у Border элементов, до сих пор не могу понять вашу задачу....

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Обновил

Comment: Ага, я воспроизвел ваш пример, при клике на кнопку CheckBox'ы становятся круглыми и серыми, при клике на сам чекбокс он становится круглый и красный. Что в итоге ожидаете? У вас же идет изменение CornerRadius успешно, цвет и все другое как положено.

Comment: Они становятся просто серыми, круглыми их делает  тригер (IsChecked) в стиле, и вот вопрос. Как сделать чтобы он оставался серым и круглым?

Comment: То есть один раз кликнул, нажал выбрать и они должны все время быть серыми и круглыми, в не зависимости выбран или нет, правильно понял?

Comment: Да! Все верно! Нужно именно через функцию, так как сохраненый массив будет обрабатывать их при загрузки приложения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Отвечая на сам вопрос:**

> Обращение к чекнутым чекбоксам

Вы и вправду перепутали событие Checked со свойством IsChecked.

---

Давайте теперь поговорим о ваших ошибках в целом.

1. Вы путаете WinForms и WPF, это совершенно разные платформы. В WPF принято использовать Binding, его помощником и как по мне неотъемлемая часть - MVVM.
2. По правилам MVVM вы должны разделить свое приложение четко на 3 слоя (Model - View - ViewModel). И самое важное, о View слое (то есть наше окно, xaml дизайн) другие слои совершенно не должны знать! То есть делать `cbx1.Background = Red` - не правильно!

Давайте по порядку разберем все, что у вас есть в Xaml:

```
<Grid  Margin="0,0,2,-1">
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx1" Style="{DynamicResource MyCheckBox}" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="62,59,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx4" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="62,104,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx7" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="62,150,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx2" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="107,59,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx5" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="107,104,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx8" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="107,150,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx3" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="152,60,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx6" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="152,105,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbx9" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MyCheckBox}" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" Margin="152,150,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource btn}" Content="Выбрать" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="82,205,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="89" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Что вы здесь видите?

1. Имена. Помним, да, код не должен знать о элементах. Получается они нам бесполезны.
2. Стили. У вас на все элементы привязывается один стиль, почему бы не сделать его стандартным стилем (для этого достаточно у самого стиля убрать его Key (`x:Key="MyCheckBox"`).
3. Margin. Я понимаю, вы хотели сделать сетку и все дела, но в WPF такой подход не верный! Вы не должны задавать Margin выше 10-20! Делайте сетку в самом Grid и помещайте в нужную ячейку то, что нужно.
4. Остается всякая шелуха, которая везде одна и та жа (размеры, положение и др.), почему бы ее не занести в стиль?

Переписанный код в итоге будет примерно такой:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="1" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="2" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="3" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="4" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="5" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Content="6" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="7" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Content="8" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Content="9" />
    </Grid>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource btn}" Content="Выбрать" Height="30" Width="89" Margin="0,5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Ну и стиль.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Border  x:Name="checkbx" BorderBrush="#FFC6C6C7" BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="checkbx" Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Хорошо, с ошибками покончили, давайте теперь посмотрим как можно это все удобно и правильно сделать!

---

Мы видим, что у нас идет определенное кол-во CheclBox'ов, расположены в сетке и нам надо удобно с ними работать. У нас есть два варианта 1. Это создать кучу свойств под каждый CheckBox и к ним привязываться. 2. Сделать динамическое заполнение этих кнопок и хранить их все в определенной коллекции. Как по мне, второй способ удобней, давайте реализуем:

### Xaml

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:MainViewModel}}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CheckBoxes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource btn}" Content="Выбрать" Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" Height="30" Width="89" Margin="0,5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Тут мы создаем StackPanel, которая будет расположена в верху и по горизонтали в центре, отступ со всех углов 10. Ну и для удобства, что бы в дизайнере видеть все свойства, задаем через d:DataContext тип.

В StackPanel задаем ItemsControl, который будет размещать CheckBox'ы в сетке UniformGrid, которая размечает нашу область на равные 3х3 клетки. Самому ItemsControl задаем ItemsSource - это привязка к коллекции, в которой мы содержим все необходимые свойства для наших CheckBox'ов. У самих же CheckBox'ов мы делаем привязку к нужным свойствам (Content и IsChecked). А, ну и не забываем про саму кнопку, которая также размещена внутри StackPanel, у нее все по стандарту, единственное - Click поменяли на команду (опять же, MVVM и в нем желательно использовать команды).

Также нам нужно немного подправить стиль, а точнее его триггеры, ведь мы помним, что в MVVM делится все на слои и не есть хорошо в коде задавать цвета, ведь это задача View слоя. Перепишем триггеры следующим образом:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlreadyUsed}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        <Setter TargetName="checkbx" Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
        <Setter TargetName="checkbx" Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Тут добавляется DataTrigger, который проверяет наше свойство AlreadyUsed, если оно true, то задаем нужный цвет и др. свойства.

### Код

В коде сразу первым делом делаем основных два класса:

**INotifyPropertyChanged** - Этот класс поможет нам узнать об изменениях наших свойств.

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand** - Этот класс поможет в создание команд.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Эти классы можно положить где нибудь в дальнем углу проекта и забыть, изменений в них делать вряд ли нужно будет. Ну чтож, создадим модель самих CheckBox'ов. В ней нам надо создать свойства для привязки и к тем, что могут измениться надо реализовать INPC:

```
public class CheckBoxModel : VM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => isChecked;
        set
        {
            isChecked = !AlreadyUsed && value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool alreadyUsed;
    public bool AlreadyUsed
    {
        get => alreadyUsed;
        set
        {
            alreadyUsed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

У свойства IsChecked можно увидеть некую проверку, которая не дает выделить объект, если его AlreadyUsed = true.

Ну что, считай последний шаг! Основная ViewModel! В ней нам нужно сделать коллекцию, заполнить ее и создать команду для кнопки:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxModel> CheckBoxes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxModel>();
    public RelayCommand SelectCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            CheckBoxes.Add(new CheckBoxModel{Name = i.ToString()});
        }

        SelectCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Select());
    }

    private void Select()
    {
        var items = CheckBoxes.Where(x => x.IsChecked);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            item.AlreadyUsed = true;
            item.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

- **CheckBoxes** - наша основная коллекция, она ObservableCollection потому, что данная коллекция уже имеет необходимое для оповещения интерфейса при изменениях внутри коллекции.
- **SelectCommand** - Команда нашей кнопки.
- **Конструктор** - Через него я для теста с помощью цикла добавляю 10 элементов, i передаю в название. Также инициализирую команду, привязываю ее к методу `Select()`.
- **Метод Select** - Данный метод будет вызываться при нажатие на кнопку, в нем наша задача состоит в том, что бы взять все выделенные элементы и задать им AlreadyUsed. Ну и убрать само выделение.

Все, теперь смело можем привязать наше окно к MainViewModel и наслаждаться результатом! Пишем в MainWindow что то на подобие этого:

```
private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = MainViewModel;
}
```

Результат:

[image: Result]

---

> показа данных о том сколько кнопок было выбрано

Тут ооочень простое решение. У нас уже все необходимое есть, главным источником данных является MainViewModel. Так давайте создадим в ней необходимое свойство. Так, как свойство динамичное (обновляется время от времени), то нам надо еще INPC:

- Наследуем VM класс `public class MainViewModel : VM`.
- Создаем свойство со счетчиком:

  ```
  private int boxCount;
  public int BoxCount
  {
      get => boxCount;
      set
      {
          boxCount = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
      }
  }
  ```
- Меняем ObservableCollection на BindingList (она оповещает совершенно обо всех изменениях в коллекции):

  ```
  public BindingList<CheckBoxModel> CheckBoxes { get; set; } = new BindingList<CheckBoxModel>();
  ```
- В конструкторе MainViewModel подписываемся на событие обновления коллекции:

  ```
  CheckBoxes.ListChanged += CheckBoxesOnListChanged;
  ```
- Ну и делаем, что нам нужно при изменениях:

  ```
  private void CheckBoxesOnListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      BoxCount = CheckBoxes.Count(x => x.IsChecked);
  }
  ```
- Остается у определенного элемента привязать его текст к нашему новому свойству, я поменяю content у кнопки. `Content="{Binding BoxCount}"`.

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Подход к делу на высшем уровне, но как же вам не лень делать это для других... =)

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov Когда есть время, желание и нет других дел, то почему бы и нет? Я за грамотных программистов, которые потом может меня чему нибудь сами да научат xD

Comment: Пожалуй вы правы. А не подскажите, как делать такие GIF-ки с экрана как у вас в ответе?

Comment: @ArthurEdgarov [LICEcap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо огромное, шикарное объяснение! Только вот я использовал массивы именно с целью сохранения состояния и запуска приложения с уже выбранными чек боксами, а также показа данных о том сколько кнопок было выбрано.

Comment: @Rarr Ну так что мешает сделать все, что вам нужно? Ваша коллекция находится в MainViewModel, называется CheckBoxes. Делайте с ней все. что вашей душе будет угодно. Сохраняйте ее состояние и загружайте в нее что надо, получайте кол-во элементов (к примеру так `var count = CheckBoxes.Count(x => x.IsChecked);`). Да с такой моделью вы вообще все без труда сделать теперь сможете)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ пытаюсь разобраться, но много очень ошибок, в частности с INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Rarr каких именно?

Comment: Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен

Comment: @Rarr .NET какой используете?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Framework 4.1.6

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77969/discussion-between-evgeniyz-and-rarr).

Comment: Здесь вместо Grid лучше подошел бы UniformGrid с Columns="3" - разметка бы короче получилась

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я почему то предполагал, что именно вы это напишите =). Моя задача была пройтись по ошибкам и показать их автору (а  не сократить код), автор вопроса использовал Grid, я думаю правильней было бы показать как его использовать (что я и сделал). Уже после можно заметить, что я переписал всю разметку с нуля и там использовал UniformGrid.

Comment: Ага, вижу. Не внимательно смотрел до этого

Answer (score 1):

```
cbs[i, j].Checked
```

Это обработчик события.

В условии нужно писать `cbs[i,j].IsChecked == true`