# WPF Постепенная подгрузка в datagrid из БД

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Добрый день у меня есть контекст Library, таблица Books. С помощью метода Load() я загружаю в Local данные и потом local привязываю к datagrid. Как мне организовать постепенную подгрузку из базы данных. То есть при запуске в кэш грузится вся таблица, и только когда она догрузится datagrid приступит к отображению, что при 15 тысяч записей очень долго.
Если плохо объяснил есть проект на GitHub, критика по поводу других аспектов проекта приветствуется.
https://github.com/flash1371/DigitalLibrary

Comment: А можно один маленький вопрос, чисто ради своего любопытства... Я так понимаю вы студент, вас учили MVVM или вы сами решили по нему писать все?

Comment: Сам решил, я не уверен, что нормально реализовал, но мне интересно было хотя бы попробовать

Comment: Вы знаете в чем суть MVVM паттерна? Ну, основная..

Comment: Отделение логики от представления. Если накосячил сразу скажите в чём ошибка

Comment: Именно, отделение. Все разделяется на 3 слоя - Model, ViewModel и View. О View не должен знать не один кусочек кода, он должен быть независим. А теперь смотрим ваш код: [тут](https://github.com/flash1371/DigitalLibrary/blob/master/DigitalLibrary/View/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L14) вы передаете MainWindow в ViewModel, а [тут](https://github.com/flash1371/DigitalLibrary/blob/master/DigitalLibrary/ViewModel/LibraryViewModel.cs#L56) допустим вы берете дочерние элементы во View, в UniformGrid. Вот уберите все `Name="..."` с кода, запустится ли приложение? Нет, а должно. По этому у вас MVVM вообще нет.

Comment: Спасибо, буду исправлять

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/pics/22.1.png 
На этом ресурсе View и ViewModel связаны друг с другом, и получается о View знает ViewModel или я не так понял?

Comment: Что касается "подгрузки", то тут у вас не должно браться 15 тысяч записей с базы, для таких целей делают пагинацию (страницы), то есть страница 1 - `list.Skip(0).Take(15);`; страница 2 - `list.Skip(15).Take(15);` ну и так далее. Вы хоть раз видели нормальный сайт/приложение, которое выводит больше скажем 100 значений? Я лично нет...

Comment: Обновление данных имеется - это методами привязок, которые оповещают интерфейс об измененных данных в коллекции. Из кода связи не какой нет (ну кроме DataContext и то, он должен быть на уровне выше, в App к примеру, до инициализации View.).

Comment: Я исправил, вроде как по паттерну, но что-то мне подсказывает что я нагромоздил лишнего

Comment: Прошелся бегло по изменениям, ну что же... Уже намного лучше! Пару замечаний. 1. Вы все реализовали по принципу DependencyProperty - данный подход хорош в UserControl или подобных местах, у вас же обычная ViewModel, где достаточно будет обычного свойства, ну и реализация INPC там, где требуется. 2. По принятым чтоль стандартам каждая VM, M должна заниматься своей определенной задачей. У вас все в одном месте, и студенты, и библиотека, это лучше разделять по разным классам и по своей VM.

Comment: 3. Click у кнопок - по сути, это допустимо, но это частичная реализация MVVM, полный же MVVM должен состоять из команд (ICommand). Ну и 4. Не помню говорил ли, но DataContext не очень хорошо задавать в самой View, ибо таким образом она становиться зависима от определенной VM. Честно, тут и сам толком не разобрался что да как, но по сути это должно быть на уровне выше, скажем в App классе, до показа самого окна.

Comment: Спасибо, всё понял, кроме момента "достаточно будет обычного свойства", не могли бы вы скинуть пример

Comment: Да любой мой ответ возьмите по WPF) К примеру, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/833104/220553) - В `CheckBoxModel` реализуются обычные свойства, допустим `public string Name { get; set; }`, но, оно не будет оповещать View об изменении из ViewModel, по этому надо реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` - создаем для удобства класс, наследуем нашу VM от него и переписываем свойство так, как к примеру реализован `public bool IsChecked`.

Comment: Теперь понял. То что вы так подробно описываете решение и проблемы вызывает только уважение. И ещё раз спасибо

Comment: Да на здоровье, удачи в изучении ;-)