# Как отрисовать данную ветку интерфейса WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется данный кусочек интерфейса, нужно его отрисовать, но не знаю как, подскажите.
Был бы благодарен если ещё и с объяснением, сфера новая, пытаюсь разобраться

```
<Button  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="153,132,25,35">
  <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <Image Margin="0" Source="Resources/Nolik.png"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Что в вашем понимание "Отрисовать" ?

Comment: Здесь видно как отрисовывают поле из 9-ти картинок, извините, может я не правильно понимаю данный процесс т.к. новичок https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeUOwWKWfaI&t=500s

Comment: В данном видео разрабатывают приложение на `WinForms`, с `WPF` у него совершенно разный подход по работе с View (тем, что видит пользователь). В WPF формы (Form) заменены на окна (Window), которые имеют два файла, один `.xaml` - это разметка дизайна приложения (кусок из вопроса именно от туда), и `.cs` - это код данного окна (C#). Так, что советую Вам найти видео именно по `WPF`!

Comment: Я понимаю что там другая технология, но мне нужна помощь с реализацией именно в WPF. Если вы не понимаете мою проблему, то мне нужно просто при клике на кнопку нарисовать поле 3 на 3. 1 поле должно содержать структуру которая находится в содержании вопроса

Comment: Ну если вам также, как на видео, то используйте `.Children.Add()`, а не `.Controls.Add()`, у необходимого объекта установите имя (`x:Name="myName"`). Если вам хочется сделать правильно все, то в WPF не принято работать с элементами из кода, вся суть WPF в привязках (Binding) и по этому создание того, что вы хотите стоит путем привязки коллекции например к ItemControl, что то подобное я делал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/833104/220553).