# Вывод информации из бд по инициалам средствами linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Есть окно с 26 кнопками. Каждая кнопка - одна буква английского алфавита(A-Z). При нажатии на кнопку в datagrid выводится информация из таблицы и буква кнопки соответствует инициалам человека из таблицы. Короче ты тыкаешь например на кнопку E выводится Egor, жмешь на кнопку L выводится Egor Letov. Инфа получается с помощью Linq. Как быстро реализовать через события вывод информации без указания обработчика события для каждой кнопке? И как через методы расширения выбрать инфу по первой букве Фамилии и Имени при том условии что Имя и Фамилия указаны в одном столбце? Как то сумбурно составил вопрос, но готов ответить на вопросы.

Comment: Добрый день. покажите, пожалуйста, желательно с кодом, где именно вы "застопорились", как вы хотели решить задачу и что не получилось. И мы обязательно вам поможем

Comment: "Как быстро реализовать через события вывод информации без указания обработчика события для каждой кнопке?" - это как? Реализовать через события, но не указывать обработчик, ну тогда ничего и работать не будет!

Comment: @Bulson, возможно, автор имеет в виду не 26 обработчиков, а один, что было бы логичным

Comment: Во первых, да я имел ввиду то что создавать 26 обработчиков событий не рационально. Во вторых, я хотел бы уточнить то что я понимаю как отсортировать записи в таблице по первой букве. Это я делаю так: UserEntities ue = new UserEntities(); 
var data = from Users in ue.Users
                 where Users.UserName.StartWith("A")
                 select Users.UserName;
Но проблема в том что данные в UserName представлены в формате: Имя Фамилия и при выполнении вышеуказанного кода выводятся юзеры только у которых Имя начинается на A. Вопрос: как отсортировать их еще и по фамилии?

Comment: Если честно первый вопрос про события в приоритете и если не знаете как решить второй вопрос то можно забить. Прошу прощения за мою неграмотность и за то что приходится вытягивать информацию.

Comment: ну, чтобы фильровать Egor Letov по L надо перед фильром пробел поставить `.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(" L"))`, но вообще лучше конечно хранить имя и фамилию отдельно как 2 поля

Comment: в свойстве Tag можно хранить данные, подпишитесь на событие Click: this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Click) для всех кнопок и вытащите это свойство

Comment: Постарайтесь работать в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/833104/220553) направлении, не работайте с контролами через код!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Весь код я писать не буду, конечно. дам лишь вектор:
Если в свойство Tag положить, например, строковое значение, то подписавшись для каждой кнопки на событие Click, указав один и тот же обработчик, можно достать из sender значение нажатой кнопки:

```
private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var t = ((ButtonBase)sender).Tag.ToString();
}
```

что касается фильтрации по имени: хранить все в одном поле -зло). Если данные "чистые", что в реальных проектах всегда ставится под сомнение, то можно, как и написал @tym32167 в коментариях, искать с пробелом. Если же данных мало, то можно вернуть все элементы таблицы и уже тогда копаться в данных всеми доступными средствами и инструментами : разделить ФИО, фильтровать и сортировать по его составляющим

Answer (score 1):

Пример, но с кириллицей. Сделано с привязками, но без MVVM + события нажатия на кнопки.
[image: пример работы]

Класс чела такой

```
public class PersonModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //ctor
    public PersonModel(int id)
    {
        if (id <= 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(id));
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    private int _OrderNumber;
    public int OrderNumber
    {
        get => _OrderNumber;
        set
        {
            _OrderNumber = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(OrderNumber)));
        }
    }

    private string _FirstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _FirstName;
        set
        {
            _FirstName = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FirstName)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FullName)));
        }
    }

    private string _LastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get => _LastName;
        set
        {
            _LastName = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LastName)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FullName)));
        }
    }

    public string FullName => $"{LastName} {FirstName}";

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Класс поиска такой

```
public class PersonSearchModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private char _FirstNameLetter;
    public char FirstNameLetter
    {
        get => _FirstNameLetter;
        set
        {
            _FirstNameLetter = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FirstNameLetter)));
        }
    }

    private char _LastNameLetter;
    public char LastNameLetter
    {
        get => _LastNameLetter;
        set
        {
            _LastNameLetter = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(LastNameLetter)));
        }
    }

    private bool _IsSearchByName;
    public bool IsSearchByName
    {
        get => _IsSearchByName;
        set
        {
            _IsSearchByName = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSearchByName)));
        }
    }

}
```

XAML такой

```
<Grid Margin="15">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--Кнопки-->
    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Content="А"
                Click="ButtonLetter_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Content="Б"
                Click="ButtonLetter_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Content="В"
                Click="ButtonLetter_Click"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Content="Г"
                Click="ButtonLetter_Click"/>
    </Grid>

    <!--Правая сторона-->
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <StackPanel Margin="10"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Поиск по фамилии "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding SearchPerson.LastNameLetter}"/>
                <Run Text=" и имени "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding SearchPerson.FirstNameLetter}"/>
                </TextBlock>
                <CheckBox Content="сначала Имя"
                          IsChecked="{Binding SearchPerson.IsSearchByName}"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <Button x:Name="_buttonClearSearch"
                    Content="Сбросить"
                    Height="30"
                    Width="70"
                    Click="ButtonClearSearch_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Н/П" Binding="{Binding OrderNumber}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Сотрудник" Binding="{Binding FullName}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Бехайнд код окна такой

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Источник данных
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IRepository _repository = new TestRepository();

    //INPC
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = this;

        LoadData();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Список Людей
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> People { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Поисковый объект
    /// </summary>
    private PersonSearchModel _SearchPerson;
    public PersonSearchModel SearchPerson
    {
        get => _SearchPerson;
        set
        {
            _SearchPerson = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SearchPerson)));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Начальная загрузка данных
    /// </summary>
    private async void LoadData()
    {
        var people = await _repository.GetPeopleAsync();

        people = SetOrderNumbers(people);

        People = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>(people);
        SearchPerson = new PersonSearchModel { FirstNameLetter = '?', LastNameLetter = '?' };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Сортировка и нумеровывание по порядку Людей
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="people"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<PersonModel> SetOrderNumbers(List<PersonModel> people)
    {
        var pp = people.OrderBy(p => p.LastName).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < pp.Count; i++)
        {
            pp[i].OrderNumber = i + 1;
        }

        return pp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Клавиши букв поиска
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private async void ButtonLetter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //получаем кнопку и букву на ней
        var button = sender as Button;
        var letter = button.Content.ToString();

        //в зависимости от чексбокса
        if (SearchPerson.IsSearchByName)
        {
            //искать начинаем с имени
            if (SearchPerson.FirstNameLetter == '?')
            {
                SearchPerson.FirstNameLetter = letter[0];
            }
            else
            {
                //иначе добавляем букву для фамилии
                SearchPerson.LastNameLetter = letter[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //искать начинаем с фамилии
            if (SearchPerson.LastNameLetter == '?')
            {
                SearchPerson.LastNameLetter = letter[0];
            }
            else
            {
                //иначе добавляем букву для имени
                SearchPerson.FirstNameLetter = letter[0];
            }
        }

        //обновление списка Людей
        await UpdatePeople();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Обновление отображаемого списка Людей
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task UpdatePeople()
    {
        List<PersonModel> people = null;

        //если искать нечего, то просто перечитываем весь список Людей
        if (SearchPerson.FirstNameLetter == '?' && SearchPerson.LastNameLetter == '?')
        {
            people = await _repository.GetPeopleAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            //иначе пытаемся искать
            people = await _repository.SearchPeopleAsync(SearchPerson);
        }

        if (people.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Таких не найдено!", "Результат поиска",
                MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            //ButtonClearSearch_Click(null, null);
            return;
        }

        //отсортируем и пронумеруем
        people = SetOrderNumbers(people);

        //отобразим
        People.Clear();
        people.ForEach(p => People.Add(p));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка очистки поиска
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private async void ButtonClearSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchPerson.FirstNameLetter = '?';
        SearchPerson.LastNameLetter = '?';
        SearchPerson.IsSearchByName = false;

        await UpdatePeople();
    }
}
```

Весь пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/SZkOWK6ad21Tuw)