# Добавление контролов из кода

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Знаю, что код ничего не должен знать о вью. Мне надо создавать внутри StackPanel button, планирую их создавать по логике сколько строк в таблице БД столько кнопок. По клику на кнопку, она будет удаляться как из бд так и из интерфейса. У меня вопрос, с WPF знаком мало, как это сделать "правильно" что бы не из кода?

Суть(Что это) - информативная панелька для пользователя, что бы он видел что он уже привязал тот или иной аккаунт. Кнопку планирую делать стилизированную(Часть аватара + Имя(Логин)).

Comment: 1) Получить даные из БД 2) Записать их во вьюмодель 3) Обновить Datagrid/ListView на UI

Comment: Примеров с реализацией подобного на SO - уйма. Вот например [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/833104/220553) от меня, где я разбираю ошибки автора и переделываю все по правилам MVVM, создавая динамически чекбоксы. У вас должно быть примерно тоже самое, только еще про модель не забудьте, которая будет работать с базой.

Comment: @tym32167 Так правильно? То есть лепить из кнопок грубо говоря "свой контрол" это гуано?

Comment: Вы можете лепить на UI абсолютно всё, что душе угодно, пока об этом не знают ваши вьюмодель/модель и пока ваши гуи на них не влияют.

Comment: Спасибо! До ваших коментов я делал говнокод) у меня не было MVVM.